# Git branching model for teams with develop, test and deploy phases

Tags: testing, git, development-process, deployment

A developed piece of code goes these phases in our team:

1. Developers write the code
2. Then they send it to testers
3. If tests pass, then testers send the change/new feature/bugfix to operations team for deployment.

Currently, we've adopted the following approach:
 We have a `master` branch from which we create one or more custom branches to make our new commits. Then we send a pull request to the `release` branch along with the task to test the newly developed code. If tests pass the testers merge the commits to `release` branch, create a pull request from `release` to `master` and open a deployment task. After the deployment, the changes are merged to `master`.

But there a problem here. We're never sure that the production runs the code that's in the `master` branch, because a human factor is involved. So next time when I want to create a branch from `master` I'll have to check if all the previous changes are reflected in it.

Can someone suggest a better flow? What are the best practices for this kind of situations?

P.S. I know automating the whole software development-deployment lifecycle would probably solve many problems, including this one, but currently we're a bit away from full automation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if [Feature Flags, Toggles, Controls](http://featureflags.io/) is something that you have looked into. But it might be good to know about them, as they solve the branching / merging issue in a complete different way!

There is also a nice article [Feature Toggles (aka Feature Flags)](https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html), written by Martin Fowler.